# Capturing File Names with Embedded Microsoft Forms

Tags: powerpoint, power-automate, microsoft-forms

I am currently utilising Microsoft Forms to collect feedback from customers by embedding the same form in various PowerPoint files. To enhance my data tracking capabilities, I am interested in capturing the name of the PowerPoint file associated with each response.

I have explored the use of Power Automate's "Get response details" feature, but it seems that the file name is not automatically captured. Therefore, I have the following inquiries:

a. Is it possible for Microsoft Forms to capture the file name when embedded in PowerPoint or any other Microsoft Office application?

b. If yes, could you please guide me on how to retrieve the file name associated with each response?

Any guidance, insights, or alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated as this would significantly enhance my feedback collection process. Thanks in advance!